# Random Noise in GANs

Tags: gan

What does the "random input" from noise (random noise) mean in GANs?

Let's say I want to synthesize data such as name, age, income etc.. Does my generator know the original data sets (and thus the distributions of the data)?

How can I think of "random noise" in this scenario?

Comment: does [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-do-gans-need-so-much-noise-1eae6c0fb177) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the page.

Comment: Alright! Thanks already :)

Comment: Effectively what it says is that GANs generate **new** data which follow some distribution (learned from old data), so novelty requires some quite simple random input. Then it goes on to say that not any random input will do, it has to match the output dimensions

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not clutter your posts with irrelevant and unhelpful introductions, sorrys. thanks etc (edited out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs), the random noise is weighted by the learned feature maps to generate novel, synthetic data examples.

If there was no random input to the generator network, it would create the same synthetic data example over and over. The noise acts as a random seed.